# How can I determine if NX is enabled on AMD A6?

Tags: nx

How can I determine if the NX bit is enabled? What I am doing right now is trying to run rdmsr, but I get an error:

```
rdmsr:pread: Input/output error
```

This is when I do:

```
rdmsr 0x1a0
```

The CPU is an AMD A6 3400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics.

I am running Fedora 18, and the reason I want to check if the NX bit is enabled is because I'm getting an Error Code 0x0000005D while trying to install windows 8 on Gnome Boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, or at least I think I did. If I am wrong, please correct me.

Reading on page 55 of the "AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 2: System Programming" (http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24593_APM_v2.pdf#G11.1043852), to which I found a link on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register), I learned that the address of the Extended Feature Enable Register, which is where the NXE bit is located, is C0000_0080h, not 0x1a0. Based on that, I did this:

```
sudo rdmsr -f 11:11 C0000_0080h
```

Which returns a zero (0), which according to the manual, means the bit is not enabled.

This doesn't exactly solve my problem with installing Windows 8 on Gnome Boxes, but I think it answers the question of how to determine if the NX bit is enabled on AMD A6 chips.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the rdmsr tool is incorrect. You are specifying the address in correctly.

You should use it like this:

```
sudo rdmsr -f 11:11 0xc00000080
```

This will give you the correct bit value other wise you will get 0 each time without any error.

Now you can set the value using the `wrmsr` tool the same way.

```
sudo wrmsr -p processor_no address value
```

So in this case it should be  like this

```
sudo wrmsr 0xc0000080 0xvalue
```

Tested on AMD..

Comment: That gives me the following error `rdmsr:pread: Input/output error`

Comment: @ At Which step?

Comment: first step `sudo rdmsr -f 11:11 0xc00000080`

Comment: Follow the steps in this blog to check if your kernel has support for this and if you have correctly inserted the kernel module required for this. If you are able to solve your issue do post it here.

Comment: http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/09/19/howto-using-cpu-msr-tools-rdmsrwrmsr-in-debian-linux/